# Splitting string into array upon token

Tags: string, bash, arrays, logging

I'm writing a script to perform an offsite rsync backup, and whenever the rsyncline recieves some output it goes into a single variable. I then want to split that variable into an array upon the **^M** token, so that I can send them to two different logger-sessions (so I get them on seperate lines in the log).

### My current line to perform the rsync

> `` result=`rsync --del -az -e "ssh -i $cert" $source $destination 2>&1` ``

### Result in the log, when the server is unavailable

> ssh: connect to host *offsite* port 22: Connection timed out^M rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]

Comment: My window of testing is closed for this time... Offsite is back up. And my head hurts for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, trough a mix of your answers, I came up with a working solution. Here it is.

```
result=`rsync --del -az -e "ssh -i $cert" $source $destination 2>&1`
IFS=$'\n'
for variable in $result; do
    logger $variable
done
unset IFS
```

Now the entire script works!

Answer (score 1):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -a foo <<< $'12\n345\n67'
echo "${foo[@]}"
```

Comment: The herestring redirection (`<<<`) is only valid in bash, not sh.

Comment: Ah, using bash to interpret instead of sh, made it better... But I still could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

`^M` is `$'\r'` so you might try that as your delimiter:

```
IFS=$'\r' read -ar result <<< $(rsync --del -az -e "ssh -i $cert" $source $destination 2>&1)
echo ${result[0]}   # first part
echo ${result[1]}   # second part
```

Comment: Almost right, the ^M is sent out by my SSH-client, when it throws this error, trought rsync. So it still comes out as a ^M, but I've gotten it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=$'\r'
set -- $result
echo $1
echo $2
```

Comment: I get weird break on this logger only gets `ssh: co`

Comment: also, the scripts appear to hang after that.

Comment: use `\r` and see how the result go.

Comment: About the same response, instead, ut breaked on the first r... I don't know why, but I've gotten the whole script working. Solution is posted.

Comment: Try escaping the backslash: `\\n` or `\\r`